# what does "__fortify_fail" do?

Tags: security, gcc, debian

a user submitted a bug-report, where my application segfaults in "__fortify_fail()".

i understand that this is related to building my application with Debian's "hardening" flags `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector`.

unfortunately the [backtrace](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=690410) of the user does not tell me much yet, and the user is not super responsive (right now).

in order to understand better what is going on, i would like to know, what `__fortify_fail` actually does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function is normally just an error reporter. Sample code from glibc is:

```
extern char **__libc_argv attribute_hidden;

void
__attribute__ ((noreturn))
__fortify_fail (msg)
     const char *msg;
{
  /* The loop is added only to keep gcc happy.  */
  while (1)
    __libc_message (2, "*** %s ***: %s terminated\n",
                    msg, __libc_argv[0] ?: "<unknown>");
}
libc_hidden_def (__fortify_fail)
```

It may be called here and there where sources is preferred to be fortified. "Fortification" itself is just a couple of run-time checks. Sample usage in `openat` function from `io/openat.c` is:

```
int
__openat_2 (fd, file, oflag)
     int fd;
     const char *file;
     int oflag;
{
  if (oflag & O_CREAT)
    __fortify_fail ("invalid openat call: O_CREAT without mode");

  return __openat (fd, file, oflag);
}
```

Without fortification, `O_CREAT` is acceptable without mode (still this case is highly suspicious, it **is** legal).

Think about `__fortify_fail` like about printf+abort.

Turning telepathy on about your question, I may suggest that user have some problems with using libc in user code. `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xebdf0)[0x7f75d3576df0]` is a place inside libc where some runtime-check fails, so `pd[0x49b5c0]` is a place where libc incorrectly called from.